# I want to make bootstrap/css responsive carousel, with text on left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel, responsive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90DD.jpg)
I want to make slider like which looks same on all devices

```
<div class="carousel-inner slider-p">
<div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/hero_img.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Beauty anywhere, anytime!</h5>
            <p>
              Grow your business by letting your potential customer <br> find you with just a tap of finger
            </p>
            <button class="slider-btn btn">Parther with us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducable code to help you with your problem.

Comment: I'm trying this above code

Comment: Can you make a stackblits out of it?